# Linq grouping multiple where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that I wrote in SQL, which works, and I am trying to move this to the appropriate LINQ statement, and can't seem to get it quite right.

The SQL query:

```
select sku
from Table
group by sku
having count(sku) > 1 and count(distinct(unit)) > 1
```

and what I have so far with LINQ

```
    var dupCount = (from val in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    group val by new {sku = val[4]} into grp
                    where grp.Count() > 1 && grp.unit.Distinct().Count() > 1
                    select grp).ToList();
```

I cant seem to figure out how to tell the where within the group to only pull the records with a distinct "unitreserve".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant seem to figure out how to tell the where within the group to only pull the records with a distinct "unitreserve".

`Select` the "unitreverse" field, apply `Distinct` and then `Count` it:

```
where grp.Count() > 1 && 
      grp.Select(dr => dr["unitreserve"]).Distinct().Count() > 1
```